# Invalid KC-API-SIGN error with Kucoin API

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, kucoin

I have been coding in Python the Kucoin API and I have gotten to a point at which I am stuck.
The error I get is as follows:

> API request failed with status code 401
> Error response: {"code":"400005","msg":"Invalid KC-API-SIGN"}

Here is my full code, my API key, secret key and passphrase are hidden for obvious reasons.

```
import requests
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import time

# Replace with your KuCoin API key, secret, and passphrase
api_key = 'API_Key'
api_secret = 'SECRET'
api_passphrase = 'PASSPHRASE'

# Replace with your trading parameters
symbol = 'XRP-USDT'
quantity = 31.1022642448
risk_percent = 15

# KuCoin API endpoints
base_url = 'https://api.kucoin.com'
create_order_url = '/api/v1/orders'
historical_klines_url = '/api/v1/market/candles'
ticker_url = '/api/v1/market/orderbook/level1'
account_url = '/api/v1/accounts'

# Function to create a request header with authentication
def create_headers(method, endpoint, timestamp, data=''):
    str_to_sign = f'{method.upper()} {endpoint}{timestamp}{data}'
    signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(), str_to_sign.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'KC-API-KEY': api_key,
        'KC-API-TIMESTAMP': str(timestamp),
        'KC-API-PASSPHRASE': api_passphrase,
        'KC-API-SIGN': signature,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    return headers

# Function to get the current price
def get_current_price(symbol):
    endpoint = f'{ticker_url}?symbol={symbol}'
    response = requests.get(f'{base_url}{endpoint}')
    return float(response.json()['price'])

response = None

# Function to get the account balance
def get_account_balance():
    global response  # Use the global keyword to indicate that we are referring to the global variable
    try:
        endpoint = account_url
        timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)
        headers = create_headers('GET', endpoint, timestamp)
        response = requests.get(f'{base_url}{endpoint}', headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Successful response
            return float(response.json()[0]['balance'])
        else:
            # Print the error details
            print(f"API request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
            print(f"Error response: {response.text}")
            return None

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

# Function to get historical klines (candlestick data) from KuCoin
def get_historical_klines(symbol, interval, limit=100):
    endpoint = f'{historical_klines_url}?symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}&limit={limit}'
    response = requests.get(f'{base_url}{endpoint}')
    return response.json()['data']['candles']

# Function to calculate the Supertrend value (more complex example)
def calculate_supertrend(data, atr_length, multiplier):
    high_prices = [float(entry[2]) for entry in data]
    low_prices = [float(entry[3]) for entry in data]
    close_prices = [float(entry[4]) for entry in data]

    # Calculate True Range (TR)
    tr = [max(high_prices[i] - low_prices[i], abs(high_prices[i] - close_prices[i - 1]), abs(low_prices[i] - close_prices[i - 1])) for i in range(1, len(data))]
    
    # Calculate Average True Range (ATR)
    atr = sum(tr[-atr_length:]) / atr_length
    
    # Calculate the Supertrend direction (1 for up, -1 for down)
    supertrend_direction = 1 if close_prices[-1] > close_prices[-2] else -1
    
    # Calculate the Supertrend value
    supertrend = close_prices[-1] + supertrend_direction * multiplier * atr
    
    return supertrend

# Function to place a market order
def place_market_order(symbol, side, quantity):
    endpoint = create_order_url
    timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)
    data = {
        'symbol': symbol,
        'side': side,
        'type': 'MARKET',
        'quantity': quantity,
    }
    headers = create_headers('POST', endpoint, timestamp, json.dumps(data))
    response = requests.post(f'{base_url}{endpoint}', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    return response.json()

# Main trading logic
while True:
    try:
        # Get account balance
        equity = get_account_balance()

        # Get historical klines data from KuCoin
        historical_data = get_historical_klines(symbol, '1hour', limit=10)

        # Get the current price
        current_price = get_current_price(symbol)

        # Calculate Supertrend value
        supertrend_value = calculate_supertrend(historical_data, 10, 3.0)

        # Buy condition
        if current_price > supertrend_value:
            position_size = equity * risk_percent / supertrend_value
            order_response = place_market_order(symbol, 'buy', position_size)
            print(f"Buy order executed: {order_response}")

        # Sell condition
        elif current_price < supertrend_value:
            position_size = equity * risk_percent / supertrend_value
            order_response = place_market_order(symbol, 'sell', position_size)
            print(f"Sell order executed: {order_response}")

        time.sleep(60)  # Adjust the sleep interval based on your trading frequency

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        if response is not None:
            print(f"Error response: {response.text}")
```

I have been looking around for a fix for my problem but nothing seems to work as of now. I looked at the documentation and it says they error 401 means that the API key is wrong, however I can confirm it is 100% correct.

Comment: Ensure that the API key you generated has the necessary permissions for the specific endpoint you are trying to access.
And some platforms, including KuCoin, allow you to set IP whitelisting for added security.  Check if your API key is restricted to specific IP addresses, and make sure your requests originate from an allowed IP.
If there have been too many unsuccessful authentication attempts, KuCoin might temporarily lock your account.